how to transform user input into functions
i'm trying to code a numerical algorithm for approximating limits of functions in python, i'm self taught so dumb errors are to be expected.
My goal is for the user to input a function and certain parameters and get as a result a fair approximation of the value of the limit.
as for the design, i have everything designed, however the problem is that i don't exactly know how to make a function out of user input.
i thought i could use the "input()" function, however, this function outputs a string, which can be made into an int or float using their respective methods, but it doesn't output functions.
For example, if the user inputs "2X+1" As a string, i'd like to be able to turn that into a function of the form
def f(x): return 2*x + 1
but i don't know of a method that turns string input into a function neither am i capable of building one it seems. does anybody know how i could do this?

What's your plan after that (def f(x): return 2*x + 1)? What do you wanna do with the function? exec()? s = "f = lambda x: 2 * x + 1"; exec(s); print(f(2));?

Not appropriate for production use, but probably appropriate for your situation: https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/
